# Syntax to find text in string, then pull out following text until a comma is identified?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will extract partial information out of a longer string, but the string is not always consistent so I need to identify certain parts and extract based on that.

The string is legal description info on property parcels and is structured like this: `"Lot D, Plan VIP12345, Section 70, Suchandsuch District"`.  I am trying to get the `"VIP12345"` part as a separate field.

Initially I considered exporting this field as a CSV table and then separate the info into unique sections that way, but this is a dataset that gets updated regularly by replacing the entire dataset, so every time it is updated I would have to export the table, make the field a CSV table, reimport that into separate fields and then export that into something my GIS can join to.

I would rather have my GIS link to the original table with an SQL query to sort out where the Plan# is (the "VIP12345" part).  However, the Plan# does not always start with VIP, sometimes it has no letters at start, sometimes it is VIS, sometimes EPP.  The Plan# is also not always the same number of digits, sometimes it is 4 sometimes 5, sometimes 6, so i can't just count # of characters to extract from a certain point.

So I am thinking I need an SQL query that in plain language would do this: In field `[FIXLGL]` Look for the string 'Plan ' then extract all characters following that until you see a ','

I am having troubles figuring out what SQL acrobatics to use to accomplish this.  I can identify records that have a plan# `([FIXLGL] LIKE '%Plan %')` but then how to I tell the query that the important part is what is after that?

Comment: Which specific database are you using?

Comment: I assume it is SQL Server (from the brackets) but correct it if I am wrong and also edit with the version you use (2016, 2014, 2012, 2008R2, etc).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server, you can use this.

If you're not, I'll delete my answer.

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100) = N'Lot D, Plan VIP12345, Section 70, Suchandsuch District';

SELECT @s,
        SUBSTRING(@s AS string, 
                 CHARINDEX('VIP', @s),
                 CHARINDEX(',', @s, CHARINDEX('VIP', @s))
                 - CHARINDEX('VIP', @s)
                 ) AS sub
```

How does this work?

We can use [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) and the results of [charindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) to get just the parts of the string we're interested in.

Charindex is a better choice here than Patindex because it accepts a 3rd argument. The third argument tells charindex at which point in the string to *start* searching.

```
        SUBSTRING(@s, --The string
                 CHARINDEX('VIP', @s), --Charindex of VIP
                 CHARINDEX(',', @s, CHARINDEX('VIP', @s)) --Charindex of the first comma _after_ VIP
                 - CHARINDEX('VIP', @s) --Subtract the position of VIP
                 )
```

Which gives us:

```
string                                                  sub
Lot D, Plan VIP12345, Section 70, Suchandsuch District  VIP12345
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016+, you may use the new string_split function, as shown below

```
-- only applicable to SQL Server 2016+
declare @s varchar(2000)= 'Lot D, Plan VIP12345, Section 70, Suchandsuch District'

select [VIP]=substring([value], charindex('VIP', [value]), 120), [value]
from string_split(@s, ',')
where [value] like '%VIP%'
```

[image]